# treat Enum as generic?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm trying to find a way to treat enums generically but I can't find a way to make it work. Say I have several enums declared something like this:

```
public enum ABC {
    One, 
    Two,
    Three
}

public enum DEF {
    Four,
    Five,
    Six
}
```

and I want to write a method that takes an Enum as a parameter and simply returns name of the enum like this:

```
public string GetEnumName(Enum anEnum) {
    return anEnum.GetType().Name;
}
```

but if I call it like `GetEnumName(DEF)`; I get the 'is a type being used as a variable' error. Any ideas? thanks

**EDIT** Sorry judging by the replies I may not have been clear enough. I merely chose GetEnumName as a very simplistic example to illustrate the problem, not how to get the name from a type. Basically I want a method that I can pass ANY enum to and have it act on that enum directly, thanks

Comment: I think you want `typeof(DEF)`

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the enum (e.g. GetEnumName(ABC) == "ABC") or the name of one of the values (e.g. GetEnumName(ABC.One) == "One")?

Comment: More generally, can you give some examples of the expected return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will do the trick?

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetEnumName<T>(this T value) where T : struct
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("{0} is not an enum", type));
        return type.GetEnumName(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that was what I was driving at, you and romaine understood what I was after, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
public static string GetTypeName<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = GetTypeName<DEF>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are passing in the type instead of the `System.Type`.  Change your method to this:

```
public string GetEnumName(Type enumType) {
    return enumType.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to write is something like this:

```
public string GetEnumName<T>() where T : Enum
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}
```

That is, a generic method with a type parameter constraint.

Unfortunately, there is no way to define such a constraint for enums in C# (nor it is possible to define one for delegates). People usually go for the solution mentioned by @ananthonline.

In fact such constraint is not supported by the C# language but it is supported at the CLR level. Using a tool like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) for example can help you to modify your assembly and apply the constraint on the method after you get it compiled.

Have a look to this article: [Constraining generic constraints](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2012/01/13/constraining-generic-constraints)

You'll find a tool which eases the process of applying non-C#-supported generic type parameter constraints: [Cecil constraint patcher](https://github.com/jbevain/mono.linq.expressions/blob/master/tools/patch-constraints.cs)

And don't forget there are a lot of useful static methods on the [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum_methods.aspx) class if you want to work with the names and values of your enum *members*.

Comment: yes that was what I was driving at, you and ananthonline understood what I was after, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the type:

```
public string GetEnumName(Type enumType)
{
    return enumType.Name;
}
```

And

```
GetEnumName(typeof(ABC));
```

At this point if your method does nothing else you could probably just use `typeof(ABC).Name` instead.

Comment: I think he wants the name of a particular value of some enum type (defined generically) as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Generic constraints are not allowed on enum types (including System.Enum).  Use [Enum.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx?ppud=4) instead.